# fftw3 configure issue for openmp use

Tags: macos, openmp, configure, fftw

I am trying to compile fftw3 with the openmp option under mac os Lion.
As exposed in http://www.fftw.org/release-notes.html, I use the following
command line
./configure --enable-openmp

The configure stops at the line:
checking for OpenMP flag of C compiler... unknown
configure: error: don't know how to enable OpenMP

I know that openmp is given with xcode but I don't know how to give it to configure option, does anybody can help me please? I have already succeed in using openmp in other programs.

I hope this is enough information for helping me.

Thank you,

Note:
I have Xcode 4.2, gcc 4.2.1.

In the section "Output variables" of config.log, I find:

```
CFLAGS='-O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -mtune=native -fstrict-aliasing -ffast-math'
```

The failure seems to be (in the config.log):

configure:18427: gcc -std=gnu99 -o conftest    conftest.c -lm  >&5
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_omp_set_num_threads", referenced from
      _main in ccfUItzL.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:18427: $? = 1
configure: failed program was: 
/.../

Comment: Can you provide the `CFLAGS` value, and the point of failure, in the `config.log` file?

Comment: I provide the required information, is it enough?

Comment: for `gcc` the openmp flag is `-fopenmp`, you can provide it with an export CFLAGS

Comment: I did ./configure --enable-openmp CFLAGS="-fopenmp" but I got the same result

Comment: Sorry, I did: I did ./configure --enable-openmp CFLAGS=-fopenmp but I got the same result

Answer (score 1):

Looking closely, I don't think I understand how fftw3's configure test for openmp is supposed to work.

Edit the configure script; replace the two occurances of `omp_set_num_threads()` to `omp_get_num_threads()` and re-run the configure as `./configure --enable-openmp`.   Having done that, it seems to build and pass most of the tests in make check on my Macbook Pro with Lion and Xcode 4.2.1.

Keep in mind that gcc 4.2's OpenMP support wasn't very good or performant, so you may not get the most out of your multicores with fftw3 this way.

Comment: I did build fftw3 this way, but it does not pass make check. FAILED /Users/rveltz/Downloads/fftw-3.3/tests/bench:  --verify '//ofr1728' --verify '//ifr1728' --verify 'obr1728' --verify 'ibr1728' ...

Comment: Also, what would be the way et the most out of your multicores with fftw3?

Comment: Yes, one set of tests fails on my machine too this way; the tests pass with gcc 4.6.   I think you have two options; install a newer gcc (which should work, and would have better/faster OpenMP support); or build with --enable-threads instead of --enable-openmp; this uses pthreads, works with llvm-gcc4.2, and should be somewhat faster when using multiple cores.